# Issue with AVG() function in Pig Latin

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying to generate an AVG() of performances `(double)` that are listed in a data set.  I am receiving an `ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias TEST` exception, which I assume to be because TEST is empty and cannot be iterated over.

**code:**

```
flat_bus = FOREACH buss GENERATE near, name, FLATTEN(categories) AS category, stars;

bus_grouped = GROUP flat_bus BY category;

category_avg = FOREACH bus_grouped GENERATE group as grp, AVG(bus_grouped.stars);

TEST = LIMIT category_avg 10;

DUMP TEST;
```

**I tested the group function and it successfully dumps as seen below:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should get stars from flat_bus

```
category_avg = FOREACH bus_grouped GENERATE group as grp, AVG(flat_bus.stars);
```